# Dx11 vertex picking

Tags: directx, directx-11, vertex, picking

My task is to load obj file, show it to user and let him to choose specific vertices via mouse click. Then give information about this vertex.
I've got now loading and showing 3d object, but i dont know how to show vertices instead of solid object, and whats more important how to different clicked vertex from others.
I'm using code from: http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11OBJMODEL

Comment: To visualize the mesh as points, you could just set its topology to POINTS. More optimally, you would filter duplicate vertices. Optionally, you can implement a geometry shader that increses the point size. For picking, you just have to google a bit. There are lots of examples out there. It can either be done via geometry analysis or via a separate buffer that stores rendered vertex ids.

Comment: Do i have to use billboarding in geometry shader to render every vertex as a quad with a picture (of yellow dot for example). Or is there simpler method to make vertex more visible (I changed topology to POINTS already)

Comment: You don't have to but it's an option. Actually, one of the simpler ones.